# How do I pre-determine LP ID (Raydium) on the basis of a given OpenBook market ID

Tags: serum-market, raydium

Trying to do this before the pool is initialised,I am pretty sure that this can be done just not sure on the exact implementation.

```
findProgramAddress([RaydiumAuthV4,"something", "something"],RaydiumAuthV4)
```